# how to select different items of checklistbox by typing its id

Tags: c#

i want to select  different items of checklistbox by typing its only id in textbox.
those items contain employee name and its id.
my code goes like this:

```
    private void txtEmpID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectEmployeeList(txtEmpID.Text);
    }


    public string ParseName(string Name)
    {
        Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"[^\d]");
        string EMP_ID = regexObj.Replace(Name, "");
        return EMP_ID;
    }


    public void SelectEmployeeList(string str)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < chkListBoxLoadName.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string Name = ParseName(chkListBoxLoadName.Items[i].ToString());
            if (str == Name)
            {
                chkListBoxLoadName.SetItemChecked(i,true);
            }
            else
            {
                chkListBoxLoadName.SetItemChecked(i,false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice code, now where does it go wrong? I do "sort of" understand your question but I don't see the issue in your code. I mean the code could use some improvements here and there. But please describe the problem in more detail, perhaps pointing to lines in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need use Regular expressions for this.
Simple solution is to use Linq and string arrays like this (in my example in EventHandler for TextChanged):

```
string[] blocks = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Split(' ');
  for (int idx = 0; idx < clb_CheckedListBox.Items.Count; idx++)
    clb_CheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(idx, clb_CheckedListBox.Items[idx].ToString().Split(' ').Intersect(blocks).Any());
```

You can run fully example with this next code (I can not upload image, so I paste here fully content of running main .cs file):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Example());
        }
    }

    public partial class Example : Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox clb_CheckedListBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txb_TextBox;

        public Example()
        {
            this.clb_CheckedListBox = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox();
            this.txb_TextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.clb_CheckedListBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.clb_CheckedListBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "John 1455", "Jenny 786", "Bob 410", "Adam 97", "Jennifer 4100"});
            this.clb_CheckedListBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.clb_CheckedListBox.Name = "clb_CheckedListBox";
            this.clb_CheckedListBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(168, 139);
            this.txb_TextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(187, 13);
            this.txb_TextBox.Multiline = true;
            this.txb_TextBox.Name = "txb_TextBox";
            this.txb_TextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(205, 139);
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(404, 166);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txb_TextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.clb_CheckedListBox);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

            this.txb_TextBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txb_TextBox_TextChanged);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.TestForm_Load);
        }

        private void txb_TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] blocks = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Split(' ');
            for (int idx = 0; idx < clb_CheckedListBox.Items.Count; idx++)
                clb_CheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(idx, clb_CheckedListBox.Items[idx].ToString().Split(' ').Intersect(blocks).Any());
        }

        private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.txb_TextBox.Text = "John 410 Jennys 970 4100";
        }
    }
}
```